# How can I use Intel HAXM for a Windows VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, intel, hyper-v, haxm

I'm wondering if Intel HAXM can be utilized to start a Windows VM like you can using the Windows Hyper-V virt technology?

Answer (score 0):

No. HAXM was designed to emulate Android only and can not be used to emulate Windows.